# Can anyone provide any tips regarding a development environment for SilverStripe?

Tags: development-environment, silverstripe

I'm pretty new to developing with SilverStripe. At the moment I'm using Firefox / Kate for development on the new platform.

I was wondering what other people use? Has anyone used Eclipse with any success? Are there any other IDEs / environments / approaches that work well with SilverStripe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com), an Eclipse based IDE.

I'd recommend searching on here for PHP IDEs for a better answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try using [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/php/index.html) for PHP-development, works great for me.

Comment: +1 I tried Eclipse and Zend Studio, and then NetBeans, and i have to say it is way better (for PHP)

Answer (score 1):

I use Zend Studio 5.5 which is no longer distributed since they replaced their custom app with a Eclipse variant. I would go with Aptana Studio if you think about going with an Eclipse variant.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you can syntax highlight .ss files like .php and you are fine with any that let you see your whole project as you will jump to/from */mysite* and */themes* folders quite often.

Answer (score 0):

The Silverstripe documentation recommends the PHP Development Tools PDT for Eclipse amongst others: http://doc.silverstripe.org/tools